# This app require specific features not available on this device

Tags: ios

In iOS app Store,the following message is showing in my app installation page.
"This app require specific features not available on this device" .
What is the issue, how to fix it.
Issue found only in iPhone 5s, iPhone x, iPad Air[image]
[image]

Comment: Since we can't see what metadata is attached to the app, you would probably have better luck asking Apple.

Comment: Check your info.plist; do you have anything specified for UIDeviceCapabilities?

Comment: @Paulw11 i attached the info.plist file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the "Device Compatibility" section for your app in the App Store I can see that only Wi-Fi+Cellular iPads and the latest generation iPad Pros are supported.

[image]

You have added `gps` to the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in your info.plist file.

Non-cellular (Wi-Fi only) iPads do not have a GPS receiver and will not meet this hardware requirement.

I am not sure why you are unable to install on an iPhone 5S or iPhone X;  There may be restrictions in place on those specific devices.  I was able to install the app on an iPhone X.

If you require GPS-level location accuracy then your app will not be compatible with non-cellular iPads.

You can remove the gps requirement but location may be less accurate in devices without a GPS receiver as it will rely on WiFi location.

Comment: "I am not sure why you are unable to install on an iPhone 5S or iPhone X; Perhaps on those specific devices the user has disabled location services?" Because he's looking at the iPad version of the app. Notice the "offers iPhone app" button for seeing the iPhone version.

Comment: Maybe; I was assuming that he got the same message from the App Store on the iPhones in question. The compatibility says that the app is universal and I can install it on an iPhone 8

Comment: You could be right. It certainly doesn't make any objection to installing on my iPhone 6s.

Comment: I was also able to install it on an iPhone X